# Terminal Emulator Problem Mac Spoof

Tags: wi-fi, root-access, mac-address

I'm trying to do a Mac Spoof from my Motorola Moto E (Rooted of course!) but I have a problem cause i'm quite sure i'm not succeeding in spoofing!
Well, I installed BusyBox and Terminal Emulator.
Then I go to Terminal Emulator and wrote:
**"su"**  (so I have permission from SUPERSU)

```
root@surnia_umts : /  # **busybox ifconfig wlan0 down**

root@surnia_umts : /  # **busybox ifconfig wlan0 hw ether [New Mac]**

root@surnia_umts : /  # **busybox ifconfig wlan0 up**
root@surnia_umts : /  #
```

Then the terminal doesn't say anything else.

After that,  the wifi from the device doesn't work anymore ( I have to disable and renable the wifi to make it work again) and of course the mac didn't change...... anyone has an idea, need some help, I am new of Android!!!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Android MAC Spoofing can only be accomplished on "Open" access wifi networks. Try to change the last three sets of numbers from the original mac address. The first three sets identify the adapter/manufacturer, changing them may cause authentication issues.